# Writing haskell types pointfree (or other ways to write type-level functions)?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Are there combinators to write Haskell types in pointfree style?

I have a type synonym that is something like:

```
type FooT m a = StateT State (ReaderT (Params m) m)
```

I'd like to be able to write the right-hand-side of this in pointfree style in order to instantiate a typeclass that demands a parameter be a monad transformer. ie, there is some typeclass like:

```
class (MonadTrans t, Bar (t Monad)) => Baz t where -- where Bar is some other typeclass
 ...
```

And I would like to instantiate it with my stack of transformers. However, I need to provide it with something of kind `(* -> *) -> * -> *`, which means I would need to write a type-level function in order to pass my `StateT State (ReaderT ...)` transformer as a parameter to the typeclass.

I tried using type families but it seems like they need to be fully applied.

Answer (score 5):

You must use `newtype`. Type synonyms have to be fully applied, so they do not actually give you a way to rearrange type expressions to fit certain kinds.

The simplest is to turn `FooT` into a newtype:

```
newtype FooT m a = FooT (StateT State (ReaderT (Params m) m) a)
```

It's possible to develop a combinator style, but every combinator must be a `newtype` so that's kind of a pain to unwrap.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, TypeOperators #-}
newtype (:.:) f g a = (:.:) (f (g a))
newtype Join f a = Join (f a a)

type FooT = StateT State :.: Join (ReaderT :.: Params)
-- Good luck untangling that.
```

Comment: Gotcha, I had a newtype originally but wanted to experiment with moving away from it to see if it was causing performance issues with various instances. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @trpnd newtypes should not typically cause a performance issue, particularly if you are using `coerce` appropriately (for example, instead of writing `map coerce`, you just write `coerce`). They do not introduce any runtime wrapping and they have the same runtime representation as the type they are “wrapping”